# Triggers, the flow of the program does not stop

Tags: sql, oracle

I made a simple program on Oracle Forms. The code below is the trigger when the submit button is pressed.

Here it is:

```
BEGIN
CREATE_RECORD;

IF :USERS.USERNAME IS NULL THEN
    MESSAGE('Please enter Username');
    GO_ITEM('USERNAME');

ELSIF :USERS.PASSWORD IS NULL THEN
    MESSAGE('Please enter Password');
    GO_ITEM('PASSWORD');

ELSIF :USERS.PASSWORD2 IS NULL THEN
    MESSAGE('Please confirm your Password');
    GO_ITEM('PASSWORD2');

ELSIF :USERS.PASSWORD != :USERS.PASSWORD2 THEN
    MESSAGE('Password did not match');
    GO_ITEM('PASSWORD2');

ELSIF :USERS.NAME IS NULL THEN
    MESSAGE('Please enter your Name');
    GO_ITEM('NAME');

ELSIF :USERS.POSITION IS NULL THEN
    MESSAGE('Please enter your Position');
    GO_ITEM('POSITION');

END IF;

IF :USERS.ACCESS_LEVEL = 'admin' THEN

    IF :USERS.ADMIN_PASS = 'eweb1' THEN

        alert:= show_alert('USER_CREATED');

            IF alert = alert_button1 THEN
            MESSAGE('OK');
            END IF;

    ELSE
                MESSAGE('Administrator Password did not match');
                GO_ITEM('ADMIN_PASS');
    END IF;

    ELSE
        alert:= show_alert('USER_CREATED');

            IF alert = alert_button1 THEN
                /* foo */
            END IF;

END IF;

END;
```

When the form encounters errors, like when the second password (password2) does not match and when it shows the message saying 'Password did not match', it still flows and read the following statements instead of stopping and wait for the button to be pressed again. I hope I can fix this. tnx

Answer (score 1):

You can tell MESSAGE to wait for the operator to acknowledge the message before continuing:

```
MESSAGE('Please enter Username', ACKNOWLEDGE);
```